# SQL Server get progress

Tags: sql-server, progress-bar

Is there any way to return query work progress from SQL Server?

For example I have stored procedure that returns n rows. And I need to know how many time is it lost to finish.

Thanks.

Comment: Not really - how would SQL Server know ahead of time how many rows a given call returns? In order to find that out, it would have to actually **execute** the call - thus you've already done your query..... there's no black magic or voodoo here..... SQL Server **cannot know** ahead of time how much time a given operation will take - therefore it cannot report on progress, really....

Comment: How about a roundabout way, like getting the count of the query first? Would it be possible having that number?

Comment: Sad(. It would be very useful feature. Thanks, I will make approximate time based on statistics then.

Comment: @Louis: getting an **exact count** can be a very expensive (i.e. time-consuming) operation for a query - imagine, you have several joined tables, several conditions in the `WHERE` clause - even just finding the number of rows the query will return can be excessively expensive to do up front

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question:

"Is there any way to return query work progress from SQL Server? 
For example I have stored procedure that returns n rows. And I need to know how many time is it lost to finish."

Answer: Unfortunately, the answer is NO when returning a single query.  Within the control flow of transact-SQL or a stored procedure, you may be able to return number of rows processed or returned using the @@rowcount variable or a user defined variable that captures rows affected or returned.
If the transact-sql was using a cursor (not recommended for performance reasons), then you could return a row count after capturing a COUNT of the total number of rows to be processed or returned and then print a counter variable after completion of each loop.